# spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: nodejs, angular, ionic

Tengo un error cuando inicio el servidor en Angular, no me afecta en funcionalidad, pero me gustaria corregirlo, ya que con el NPM me da errores de instalacion.

Este es el error:

```
$ ng serve -o
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your     
browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2018-12-19T14:50:05.900Z
Hash: 8080c18c706c004f0948
Time: 8731ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 8.63 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 223 kB 
[initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] 
[rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] 
[rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.43 MB [initial] 
[rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
(node:2400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16).....
```

Los Detalles Técnicos son:

```
Sistema Operativo  Windows
Node  10.14.2 
@angular cli 7.1.3
@angular-devkit/architect 0.11.3 
@angular-devkit/core 7.1.3 
@angular-devkit/schematics 7.1.3 
@schematics/angular 7.1.3 
@schematics/update 0.11.3 
rxjs 6.3.3 
typescript 3.1.
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de angular?

Comment: Creo que debes actualizar tu app

Comment: ya probé instalando y desinstalando todo, actualmente estoy usando angular 7

Comment: Angular CLI: 7.1.3
Node: 10.14.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.3
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.3
@schematics/angular          7.1.3
@schematics/update           0.11.3
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6

Comment: ya añadi todos los componentes instalados... Esto a su vez me genera algunos errores a la hora de trabajar con otros Frameworks como Ionic.. No quiero tener que formatear mi pc.. Por favor ayuda

Comment: trata de copiar el error y pegarlo en la pregunta, agrega la version de node y npm por favor

Comment: leyedo el error, tiene que ver con la ruta del  cmd que no la encuentra la version en ingles [proponen agregar C:\Windows\System32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294118/5695795) al PATH de windows para que encuentre el comando cmd

Comment: la version del Node es 10.14.2

Comment: Error solucionado

Comment: @JonnathanCarrasco elimina todos los comentarios que hicistes y te invito a marcar tu respuesta como aceptada en un dia y ganaras dos puntos(tambien un sombrero especial por el winterbash)

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la ruta del CMD al PATH de windows, la ruta que debes agregar es la siguiente:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

Comment: Para ayudar a los demas usuarios trata de modificar la pregunta, sino sera cerrada , quita las imagen y coloca el texto de los errores